# Trouble with searchpyi.py - 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-webbrowser

I am having a little trouble trying to get this performed for output after searching. It did not happen anything such as opening web browsers. Am I doing something wrong? Your tips and advice would be so much appreciated. Here's the code I entered from the above book:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# searchpypi.py  - Opens several search results.

import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
print('Searching...')    # display text while downloading the search result page
res = requests.get('https://www.duckduckgo.com/search?q='+''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()




# TODO: Retrieve top search result links.


soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')


# TODO: Open a browser tab for each result.


linkElems = soup.select('.package-snippet')
for elem in linkElems[:5]:   # first 5 elements in list
    urlToOpen = 'https://pypi.org' + elem.get('href')
    print('Opening', urlToOpen)
    webbrowser.open(urlToOpen)
```

Comment: often  the search engines will see that your coming at it with something it thinks of as a bot. and will refuse to answer.  check if the search engine has a means of calling it that is supported.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a couple of things here

> often the search engines will see that your coming at it with something it thinks of as a bot. and will refuse to answer. check if the search engine has a means of calling it that is supported and add a user-agent to the header you are using during you r http requests
>
> there is a better way to handle query strings using the requests library rather than concatenation

So the **request** portion of your code should look something like

```
import requests, sys, webbrowser 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup      #save yourself on some unnecessary typing(and possible error) down the line  

print('Searching...')    # display text while downloading the search result page

parmas = {'q':sys.argv[1:]}
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; rv:1.0)'}

res = requests.get('https://www.duckduckgo.com/search, params=params, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
```

> Finally while working with BeautifulSoup your should consider using the `lxml` parser instead of `html.parser` cause it is generally faster and you would want that while crawling a page

Answer (score 0):

The code does not work when run exactly as written in the book (2nd edition).

The one line you need to change is written exactly as follows in the book:

```
res = requests.get('https://google.com/search?q=' 'https://pypi.org/search/?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

To get it to work, just change the code to the following:

```
res = requests.get('https://pypi.org/search/?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `requests.get` line to the following:

```
res = requests.get('http://pypi.org/search/?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Run the following from the command line (assumes file name is **Chapter 12_searchpypi.py**):

```
python "Chapter 12_searchpypi.py" "boring stuff"
```